# Regular Expression for JSON in R/Notepad++

Tags: regex, r

Here is a text in my notepadd++

```
 {"code":"US AREA","number":"00012","state":"CA"}
 {"code":"UK AREA","number":"00015","state":"UT"}
 {"code":"GERM AREA","number":"00016","state":"TA"}
```

and I want it regular expression to turn each row like this

```
 {"number":"00012"}
```

What can be the regular expression in notepad++ or in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"code"[^,]+,\s*|,\s*"state"[^}]*
```

You can use this and replace by `empty string`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/eC5iU5/1

Comment: there were no spaces between , and number  as well , and state. 
Should I just remove \s?

Answer (score 1):

You may use gsub.

```
> x <-  '{"code":"US AREA", "number":"00012", "state":"CA"}
+  {"code":"UK AREA", "number":"00015", "state":"UT"}
+  {"code":"GERM AREA", "number":"00016", "state":"TA"}'
> cat(gsub("(?:^|(?<=\n)).*?,\\s*(.*?), .*", "{\\1}", x, perl=T))
{"number":"00012"}
{"number":"00015"}
{"number":"00016"}
```

Answer (score 0):

in R:

```
library(jsonlite)
x<-fromJSON('{"code":"US AREA", "number":"00012", "state":"CA"}')[2]
toJSON(x)

{"number":["00012"]}
```

Comment: sorry but my file is huge with many fields. This was just a snippet of my complete json file.   any way to do this using regular expression

Comment: Just replace the index in code for name like this `x<-fromJSON('{"code":"US AREA", "number":"00012", "state":"CA"}')['number']; toJSON(x)`, and it can take any length vector and produce vector output. Should be quite quick as well, but regex will definitely be quicker.